# php regex for date and time

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex for validating date and time with the following format: `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss`. T is just a symbol between date and time. Thanks for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fully-powered solution:

```
function validate($str) 
{
    preg_match('/^([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})T([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})$/', $str, $matches);

    if (count($matches) != 7)
        return false;

    $valid_year   = range(2000, 2050); // your range
    $valid_month  = range(1, 12);
    $valid_day    = range(1, 31);
    $valid_hour   = range(0, 24);
    $valid_minute = range(0, 59);
    $valid_second = range(0, 59);

    list($str, $year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute, $second) = $matches;

    foreach(array('year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'minute', 'second') as $part)
    {
        if (!in_array($$part, ${'valid_'.$part}))
            return false;
    }

    return checkdate($month, $day, $year); // this will reject absurd values like February 30 or April 31
}
```

EDIT: I don't trust `strtotime`. For example: "The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 UTC to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC." (quoted from `strtotime` manual page). What if I want to accept dates out of this range? To me, `strtotime` is an unknown black-box. Don't get me wrong: I do use it, eventually! But I wouldn't for this case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex, putting letter 'T' between date regex and time regex:

```
(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})
```

Comment: This is a first step, as it will allow something like '1234-56-78T90:98:76'.

Comment: Thanks. The other part of validation is not so problematic.

Answer (score 1):

```
^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$
```

This will ensure it's in the proper format.  You would then need to call a function like strtotime to ensure it's a valid datetime as well.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that is actually needed as people/applications might have that date string entered in different formats depending on the system's locale.

What should work best, is getting the UNIX_TIMESTAMP from the given date and check if it is a valid one.

Example:

```
$date1 = "2011-02-23T13:04:41";
$date2 = str_replace("T", " ", $date1); // removing the T
$date3 = strtotime($date2);
```

Now you just check and work with $date3.. if that's valid or meets your required criteria, then the original entered date is as well.

Just in case you do not need all this mess, go plain with:

```
(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})  // pseudo - not tested
```

Answer (score 1):

This checks if the time value represents a valid date:

```
$t = strtotime($yourTimeString);

if ($t === FALSE) {
  // $yourTimeString is not valid.
}
```

If you want to verify the string format itself, use a regex check.

Comment: what about T letter? it doesn't recognize it, i guess.

Comment: This will allow date and time in several other formats other than the OP wants to validate.

Comment: The only draw back is it supports a wide range of date format.

Comment: @J.Bruni Yes. I supposed this was about finding out if the value was a valid date. Combining it with a regex check would be required to verify the string format itself.